# Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have been facing this firebase emulator error when I try to start the emulator and it stops suddenly by providing this error continuously:

> Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate
> manifest from function source: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

I tried many different processes but couldn't find any possible solution to fix this. I updated the firebase-function version as many of them gave that solution but that's not working with me.

[image]
My firebase.json file:

```js
{
  "hosting": {
    "predeploy": ["npm run --prefix client build"],
    "public": "client/out",
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/app/**",
        "function": "app"
      },
      {
        "source": "/meeting/*",
        "destination": "/meeting.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/meeting",
        "destination": "/404.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },

  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 3002
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 3001
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

package.json file of functions:

```js
{
  "name": "@minimal/minimal-kit-react",
  "author": "minimals.cc",
  "version": "2.7.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 3222",
    "build": "next build && next export",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.jsx ./src",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.jsx ./src"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.5%",
      "last 2 versions",
      "Firefox ESR",
      "not dead",
      "not IE 11",
      "maintained node versions"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "1.3.13",
    "@emotion/cache": "^11.6.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.0",
    "@emotion/server": "^11.4.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/timeline": "^5.10.1",
    "@iconify/react": "^3.1.0",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.4",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.59",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.2",
    "@nandorojo/swr-firestore": "^0.16.0",
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "change-case": "^4.1.2",
    "country-flag-icons": "^1.5.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.27.0",
    "firebase": "^9.6.1",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
    "jwt-check-expiration": "^1.0.5",
    "material-ui-phone-number": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "next": "^12.0.7",
    "next-transpile-modules": "^9.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "notistack": "^2.0.3",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "otp-input-react": "^0.2.4",
    "prevent-orientation": "^2.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-countdown": "^2.3.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-drag-drop-files": "^2.2.2",
    "react-intersection-observer": "^8.32.5",
    "react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.5.1",
    "react-number-format": "^4.9.1",
    "react-otp-input": "^2.4.0",
    "react-phone-input-mui": "^2.9.4",
    "react-phone-number-input": "^3.1.44",
    "react-quill": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "react-screen-orientation": "^0.0.4",
    "simplebar": "^5.3.6",
    "simplebar-react": "^2.3.6",
    "stylis": "^4.0.10",
    "stylis-plugin-rtl": "^2.1.1",
    "timezone-support": "^2.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@next/eslint-plugin-next": "^12.0.7",
    "eslint": "^8.4.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^12.0.7",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "prettier": "2.5.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post your error messages, logs, tracebacks or code samples as images (screenshots) - they are not indexed and thus hard to search.

Comment: The message: [`SyntaxError: Unexpected token`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unexpected_token) is mainly related to typos and syntax errors. This question (3143698) can help you to troubleshoot those ones. I will leave some similar questions that have different scenarios on what could be causing this message: (68444314, 70254904,72225579, 70027316, 70068889). Please update your post with feedback if you have tried some mentioned answers, “tried catched” the message as shown here (43012610) and share more code like your javascript or typescript.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 5):

I got the same issue which I solved by reinstalling the firebase-tool package.

`npm install -g firebase-tools`

Answer (score 1):

It may be caused because you have some empty function(function with no body) in your code, search and erase it, your issue will be solved

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. I passed through my index.js. I realized I let a function with no body...

```
async function myfunctionName()
```

I erased it, and it worked much better !